# Change bitbucket repository name on local project

Tags: android, git, android-studio, bitbucket

Im using Android Studio with bitbucket. I changed the name of a repository and now when I try to push, I get the message *Fatal error, repository not found*.
How do I update the new repository name on my Android Studio Project to push correctly?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the configuration of the remote origin in the Android Studio plugin for Version Control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simple changed the repository name accessing the config file inside the .git folder of my project. That solved the problem.

Comment: You accepted your own answer, that worked, but it is not correct, and now will lead other people to do the same. You should **never** touch anything inside the .git folder, unless you really know what are you doing

Comment: Xyaoyaoworm answer is better suited

Comment: Ok, I understand. Sorry.

Comment: No problem, just remember the next time :)

Comment: @Informatheus  
can you please help me to solve `Push failed myjob: failed with error: fatal: repository 'https://abc@bitbucket.org/abc-abc/myapp.git/' not found` this issue

Answer (score 6):

See my example:
Go to terminal,

```
cd projectFolder
git remote -v (it will show previous git url)
git remote set-url origin https://username@bitbucket.org/username/newName.git
git remote -v (double check, it will show new git url)
git push (do whatever you want.)
```

See my example:
[image]

Comment: can you please help me to solve `Push failed
myjob: failed with error: fatal: repository 'https://abc@bitbucket.org/abc-abc/myapp.git/' not found` this issue

Comment: @PranavMS can you create a question and send me the link? the information you provided here is too less to check.

Comment: Thanks i have solved the problem by changing the repository  URL to my new repository URL in the config file that is in the .git folder in my project . Then i restarted my studio. It is now working fine. .git folder may be hidden please show hidden files too . then only the folder may get visible.The problem occurred  because I  have changed the repository to new team.

Answer (score 1):

Update your git remote, changing the repo url: https://help.github.com/articles/renaming-a-remote/